# Parse a string in c# after reading first and last alphabet

Tags: c#, string

I want to cut a string in c# after reading first and last alphabet.

`string name = "20150910000549659ABCD000007348summary.pdf";`

```
string result = "ABCD000007348"; // Something like this

string name = "1234 ABCD000007348 summary.pdf";
```

After reading 1234 "A" comes and at last "s" comes so I want "**ABCD000007348**"

Comment: Can you give more details on exactly what you mean by "first and last alphabet"?  Maybe a few more examples?

Comment: Good for you!  Now, what have you done so far to accomplish your goal?

Comment: If it's a static timestamp like that then you always know you don't care about the first N digits. Will it also always end in 'summary.pdf'? If so then you can also just do a `String.Replace()` on that.

Comment: It will always end in "summary.pdf"

Comment: How about name = name.substring(17, name.lastIndexOf("summary.pdf"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use Regex:

```
string CutString(string input)
{
     Match result = Regex.Match(input, @"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+");
     return result.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say if it's always a timestamp at the beginning, I've instead opted to iterate over the string to find the first alphabetical character, rather than hardcoding `s.Remove(0, n);` where n is however many digits are in a timestamp.

```
string s = "20150910000549659ABCD000007348summary.pdf";
s = s.Replace("summary.pdf", String.Empty);

int firstLetter = 0;

foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        firstLetter = s.IndexOf(c);
        break;
    }
}

s = s.Remove(0, firstLetter);
```